# Travelling to France safe?

Tags: schengen, france, safety, event-based-effects

What happened last night was terrible and it's got me panicked. I got a Schengen visa and plane tickets to go to France next month and I am not sure I'll continue with my plan. 
Do you guys think I should risk it and go anyway?

Comment: It will be never more safe and cheaper. At every corner there will be a policeman to protect you, the remaining terrorists are gone in hiding, since the authorities are trying to hunt them down now. All hotels will looking desperately for guests, since especially the Americans don't come, because they are afraid. So prices are down. So it's now or never!

Comment: Out of curiosity: where are you from?

Comment: It probably wouldn't be a smart move to introduce yourself at the border as anything resembling your username here, though ...

Comment: Risk what? What likelhood of death counts as safe to you? At the moment, this is opinion based - if you want us to answer a safety question, you need to define clearly what you want, not just broadly ask "Is X safe"

Comment: I'm fairly sure you have several orders of magnitude more likelihood of dying in a road accident driving to the airport than of a terrorist incident on arrival!

Comment: Whatever answer you get now isn't going to give you any indication of what the situation will be in a month's time.

Comment: You might be slightly inconvenienced  by security measures, but I would have no qualms at  all safety-wise. France tightened up the borders and did things like eliminating left baggage storage when the Algerian terrorists were operating but that was no big deal for legitimate visitors. You'd be at far more danger in a U.S. city from death due to petty crime.

Comment: I'd personally have no hesitation in going. I have long suggested that the safest time to do XXX is soon after XXX restarts operation after a major disaster. Whether it is a fairground ride or transport system or other, the systems will be rererechecked, improved, monitored and fussed over. This applies to security related safety as well. While it is somewhat likely that the initiators will try again sometime, it may be in a number of countries. or somewhere obscure and inobvious or in a different manner. And pr=eople will be trying hard to outthink them.

Comment: Related question (neighbouring country, but about same safety concern): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65332/what-areas-to-avoid-in-brussels-after-the-recent-terrorism-events

Answer (score 3):

Just because there is an attack doesn't mean that the country is unsafe. Its totally safe to travel to Paris and France. Where have you heard that France was ever been a country mentioned as no go country. If you like France, go and enjoy